# gen_event handle_info not getting called

Tags: erlang, gen-event

I am using gen_event behaviour and apart from handling events, I wish to be able to handle other generic messages. According to the documentation these messages should be received through handle_info. However, this seems not to be working... unless I am missing something very obvious!

Here is my behaviour implementation:

```
-module(genevent).

-behaviour(gen_event).

-export([init/1, handle_event/2, handle_info/2, handle_call/2, terminate/2, start_link/0]).

init(_Args) -> {ok, []}.

handle_event(Event, State) ->
    io:format("***Event*** ~p~n", [Event]),
    {ok, State}.

handle_call(Call, State) ->
    io:format("***Call*** ~p~n", [Call]),
    {ok, State}.

handle_info(Info, State) ->
    io:format("***Info*** ~p~n", [Info]),
    {ok, State}.

start_link() -> gen_event:start_link({local, genevent}).

terminate(_Args, _State) -> ok.
```

And here is my usage

```
{ok,PID} = genevent:start_link(),
io:format("***Sending to*** ~p~n", [PID]),
PID ! {hello},
io:format("***Sent hello to*** ~p~n", [PID]).
```

The problem is that the code io:format("***Info*** ~p~n", [Info]) is never reached.

I hope I am not doing something very stupid!
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gen_event:start_link/1` just starts an event manager; it doesn't add your event handler to this new event manager.  You need to do that yourself with `gen_event:add_handler/3`:

```
1> c(genevent).
genevent.erl:3: Warning: undefined callback function code_change/3 (behaviour 'gen_event')
{ok,genevent}
2> {ok,PID} = genevent:start_link().
{ok,<0.38.0>}
3> gen_event:add_handler(PID, genevent, {}).
ok
4> PID ! foo.
***Info*** foo
foo
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer... I thought I had to add handlers only for events